# connecting windows store application application to localhost

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services, wcf, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to connect my windows store application to mysql database hosted on localhost. Data Connection is successful but I can't resolve Mysqlconnection function. I tried to add mysql.data reference but it didn't appear in the options. I tried adding MySql.Data.MySqlClient namespace but it didn't resolve. I have installed mysql visual studio plugin 1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `WCF` or `Web Service` to connect with your DataBase. And then make your Windows Store App to `reference the WCF or Web Service`.

Because your app will be published and installed to many clients. The direct connection client and the database is not advisable.

If you just want to test in your local machine. Here are some articles about this:

[MySQL for Windows Store apps](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/mysql_for_windows_store_apps)

[How to: Using MySQL Connector/NET with Windows Store Apps](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_using_connector_net)

Comment: Right now all i need to do is to connect store/phone app to my local database. I don't want to use web services.